# How to properly setup an RNN in Keras for sequence to sequence modelling?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

Although not new to Machine Learning, I am still relatively new to Neural Networks, more specifically how to implement them (In Keras/Python). Feedforwards and Convolutional architectures are fairly straightforward, but I am having trouble with RNNs.

My `X` data consists of variable length sequences, each data-point in that sequence having 26 features. My `y` data, although of variable length, each pair of `X` and `y` have the same length, e.g:

```
X_train[0].shape: (226,26)
y_train[0].shape: (226,)
X_train[1].shape: (314,26)
y_train[1].shape: (314,)
X_train[2].shape: (189,26)
y_train[2].shape: (189,)
```

And my objective is to classify each item in the sequence into one of 39 categories.

What I can gather thus far from reading example code, is that we do something like the following:

```
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, 26))
encoder = GRU(256, return_state=True)
encoder_outputs, state_h = encoder(encoder_inputs)
decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, 39))
decoder_gru= GRU(256, return_sequences=True)
decoder_outputs, _ = decoder_gru(decoder_inputs, initial_state=state_h)
decoder_dense = Dense(39, activation='softmax')
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)

model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
                  optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Which makes sense to me, because each of the sequences have different lengths.
So with a for loop that loops over all sequences,  we use `None` in the input shape of the first GRU layer because we are unsure what the sequence length will be, and then return the hidden state `state_h` of that encoder. With the second GRU layer returning sequences, and the initial state being the state returned from the encoder, we then pass the outputs to a final softmax activation layer.

Obviously something is flawed here because I get:

```
decoder_outputs, _ = decoder_gru(decoder_inputs, initial_state=state_h)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- 
packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 458, in __iter__
"Tensor objects are only iterable when eager execution is "
TypeError: Tensor objects are only iterable when eager execution is 
enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn.
```

[This link](https://github.com/JayParks/tf-seq2seq/issues/16#issuecomment-387922640) points to a proposed solution, but I don't understand why you would add encoder states to a tuple for as many layers you have in the network.

I'm really looking for help in being able to successfully write this RNN to do this task, but also understanding. I am very interested in RNNs and want to understand them more in depth so I can apply them to other problems.

As an extra note, each sequence is of shape `(sequence_length, 26)`, but I expand the dimension to be `(1, sequence_length, 26)` for `X` and `(1, sequence_length)` for `y`, and then pass them in a for loop to be fit, with the `decoder_target_data` one step ahead of the current input:

```
for idx in range(X_train.shape[0]):
    X_train_s = np.expand_dims(X_train[idx], axis=0)
    y_train_s = np.expand_dims(y_train[idx], axis=0)
    y_train_s1 = np.expand_dims(y_train[idx+1], axis=0)

    encoder_input_data = X_train_s
    decoder_input_data = y_train_s
    decoder_target_data = y_train_s1
    model.fit([encoder_input_data, decoder_input_data], decoder_target_data,
          epochs=50,
          validation_split=0.2)
```

With other networks I have wrote (FeedForward and CNN), I specify the model by adding layers on top of Keras's Sequential class. Because of the inherent complexity of RNNs I see the general format of using Keras's Input class like above and retrieving hidden states (and cell states for LSTM) etc... to be logical, but I have also seen them built from using Keras's Sequential Class. Although these were many to one type tasks, I would be interested in how you would write it that way too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `decoder_gru` layer does not return its state, therefore you should not use `_` as the return value for the state (i.e. just remove `, _`):

```
decoder_outputs = decoder_gru(decoder_inputs, initial_state=state_h)
```

---

Since the input and output lengths are the same and there is a one to one mapping between the elements of input and output, you can alternatively construct the model this way:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(None, 26))
gru = GRU(64, return_sequences=True)(inputs)
outputs = Dense(39, activation='softmax')(gru)

model = Model(inputs, outputs)
```

Now you can make this model more complex (i.e. increase its capacity) by stacking multiple GRU layers on top of each other:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(None, 26))
gru = GRU(256, return_sequences=True)(inputs)
gru = GRU(128, return_sequences=True)(gru)
gru = GRU(64, return_sequences=True)(gru)
outputs = Dense(39, activation='softmax')(gru)

model = Model(inputs, outputs)
```

Further, instead of using GRU layers, you can use LSTM layers which has more representational capacity (of course this may come at the cost of increasing computational cost). And don't forget that when you increase the capacity of the model you increase the chance of overfitting as well. So you must keep that in mind and consider solutions that prevent overfitting (e.g. adding regularization).

**Side note:** If you have a GPU available, then you can use [`CuDNNGRU`](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#cudnngru) (or [`CuDNNLSTM`](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#cudnnlstm)) layer instead, which has been optimized for GPUs so it runs much faster compared to `GRU`.

Comment: That worked really well, will take some time to train and then to figure out what parameters and preprocessing will work the best. I am aware that LSTM also gives the cell state, but from papers and articles it seemed that LSTM and GRU give almost identical results, with unpredictablity in which model better suits which task at hand with trial and error being a way to identify. I have a lot more work to do to understand these topics more in depth, but your answer has pushed me in the right direction, thank you!

Comment: @jupiar If you have a GPU then you can use `CuDNNGRU` layer instead which is optimized for GPUs. LSTM has more representational capacity and could preserve temporal relationships for more timesteps than GRU. Of course, at the end, it depends on the problem you are working on and the (hyper-)parameters you use.

Comment: Calling GRU, tensorflow identified my GPU, but CuDNNGRU REALLY speeded up the training! I have tried making the layers bidirectional which seems to help, my domain is speech data. But I am confused by the validation procedure, as I loop through my training data, I see a general improvement of validation accuracy, but it starts out with an average of 35%, fluctuating +-(20%), and then by the end of training, the average is at around 75%, but still fluctuating +-(20%). I pass in a random sample from validation set because data is fitted one by one in a for loop,. Is this correct precedure?

Comment: @jupiar Well, if I were you I would write a generator that yields batches of data, maybe one sample at a time (i.e. `batch_size=1`). Then I would use `fit_generator` method and pass training and validation generator to it. At the end of each epoch, you would have the validation accuracy computed over the whole val data. However, your approach is correct and the fluctuations are due to considering only one validation sample at a time (hence as you said the average accuracy is more reliable to consider). Or you can pad the input data to have a fixed-len and use `fit` method with batch_size > 1.

Comment: I've had some good results with your suggestions, varying up the hyperparameters and preprocessing etc.. . I've been trying to not use a  one to one mapping anymore, so the sequence input and the sequence output are not of the same length. I've tried to implement it by using a CTC layer on the end, but still have lots of errors. I feel there is probably a more elegant design to achieve this, could you please give some suggestions or addition to the above code for it to do this? I've been reading machine translation approaches to solving this...

Comment: @jupiar Have you looked at the [official seq2seq tutorial of Keras](https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html)? You can get some ideas from it. Further, I think if you post this as a new question with specific details and the solutions you have tried so far, other users and I would be able to help you in a better way.

Comment: I think I will do that (start a new question). I've implemented their official technique successfully, with not amazing results, so I am interested as to how much information the LSTM encoder states can hold, so the decoder can form the desired sequence, or form it in an accurate way. I see the addition of attention helps because it, for each prediction in the sequence, pulls from some distribution that exists over the input vector, but as of yet have no idea on how implement such a thing. I will first need to spend time experimenting before I come back and maybe post such a detailed question.